# Having trouble connecting AWS S3 through boto 2.49

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

The below codes work on production but failed when I tried to set it up locally.

The default host is set to s3.amazonaws.com. But I got S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden no matter I set is_secure to True or False and if I added calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat() or not.

I try to search on my S3 bucket and the endpoint is http://bucket_name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
So I set the host to s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com through environment variable.
And I got encountered SSLError exception, reconnecting for having calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat() no matter is_secure is True or False. And I got the same error for not having the calling_format but set the is_secure to True, and S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found for not having calling_format and set the is_secure to False.

The original code does not have the calling_format and is_secure argument. These were what I found in other posts.

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
c = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id='********',
                                aws_secret_access_key='*********',
                                host=endpoint)
b = c.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Comment: Maybe start to use `boto3`?!

Comment: Nice idea, but since it's working on production...